# Why there is an Exception in thread "Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner"?

Tags: java, tomcat, jtds

Thank you for suggesting to improve the question.

I am working on a full-stack application with a jdk1.8.0_181 and running on an apache-tomcat-8.5.34. According to project requirements I have jtds-1.3.1. For some reason I am getting run time exception from isValid() method in the JtdsConnection.class. As I am already using validation Query="Select 1" while creating the connection. I am very confused why this error persists at the first place. For better understanding here is the runtime exception-

***Exception in thread "Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[1694819250:1627477239682]" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:516)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:454)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.testAllIdle(ConnectionPool.java:1084)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool$PoolCleaner.run(ConnectionPool.java:1473)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)***

Also, here is my context file-

`<Resource name="jdbc/xxxx" auth="Container" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory" maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="xxxxxx" password="xxxxx" testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="true" testWhileIdle="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:xxxxxxx;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false" validationQuery="SELECT 1" />`

Please share your thoughts and work around to resolve the same.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Just so you know, best practice is to include the text of your code and error messages in the body of your question, rather than as an image. You can update your post using the 'Edit' button. (Check out the discussion behind this advice in this post on meta: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)).

Comment: The configuration that appears in your image is for a [DBCP2 connection pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database_Connection_Pool_(DBCP_2)_Configurations) (default since at least Tomcat 7), while the error comes from a Tomcat JDBC connection pool.  Please add to your question (as text) the appropriate configuration and complete stack trace. Cite also the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68548660/11748454) why you need to set `validationQuery`.

Comment: Your title might suggest that setting `validationQuery="SELECT 1"` caused the problem, while a bug in `jtds` is the problem and `validationQuery="SELECT 1"` is the attempted solution.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thank you for suggesting me the improvement. Let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: As remarked above, the resource `jdbc/xxxx` your provided is not the one causing the problem (it creates a DBCP2 connection pool). Do you have other connection pools defined?

Comment: No, it's just this one.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the DBCP Jar issue. Make sure you should have the jar that is compatible with Tomcat 8.

Tomcat 8 supports the JDBC connection pool and I am using the DBCP connection pool. Thus, I needed to use the correct DBCP.jar. The compatible jar can be found out from below link-
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html